# Reddening correction to errors

Tags: montecarlo, astronomy

When dealing with astronomical data, Should we incorporate the reddening correction to the errors of the observational parameters too?

I have applied reddening correction based on Cardelli et al to the flux.Should I do it to error in flux also?